# List<string> of Paths to Hierarchical structure

Tags: c#

I have a List of paths like that:

```
Root 
Root/Folder1 
Root/Folder1/SubFolder1.1 
Root/Folder1/SubFolder1.2
Root/Folder2 
OtherRootFolder 
OtherRootFolder/Folder1
```

I need to create a hierarchical struture with Folder + List of Children

```
public class FolderTreeModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<FolderTreeModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

How to split that paths into that structure in order to looks like:

```
Root
'-- Folder1
'---- SubFolder1.1
'---- SubFolder1.2
'-- Folder2
'-- OtherRootFolder
'---- Folder1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use `WinForm`? Look at `TreeView`

Comment: A better way to define `FolderTreeModel` is `public class FolderTreeModel : List<FolderTreeModel> { public string Title { get; set; } }`.

Comment: @Ian Depends if he want to actually display it or not. Either way, this a fantastic Friday afternoon, work-avoiding, challenge

Comment: What have you tried doing so far? Where are you having problems? The parsing of paths (could either use `Path.GetDirectoryName` or `String.Split` call)? The building of the structure after parsing the full paths?

Comment: @Rhumborl You are right, I should add, "... and *TreeNode*" ;)

Comment: My problem is with the string.split, i don't have the entire path, only relatives. i've tried many solutions but no one works =/

Comment: @Barral Then you may want to edit your question with your `string.Split` attempt

Comment: You have a perfect case of XML, not list of string.  Think on the way of List of XMNodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code you need:

```
Action<FolderTreeModel, IEnumerable<string>> ensureExists = null;
ensureExists = (ftm, ts) =>
{
    if (ts.Any())
    {
        var title = ts.First();
        var child = ftm.Children.Where(x => x.Title == title).SingleOrDefault();
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = new FolderTreeModel()
            {
                Title = title,
                Children = new List<FolderTreeModel>(),
            };
            ftm.Children.Add(child);
        }
        ensureExists(child, ts.Skip(1));
    }
};
```

Then I can do this:

```
var paths = new []
{
    "Root",
    "Root/Folder1",
    "Root/Folder1/SubFolder1.1",
    "Root/Folder1/SubFolder1.2",
    "Root/Folder2",
    "OtherRootFolder",
    "OtherRootFolder/Folder1",
};

var root = new FolderTreeModel() { Title = "/", Children = new List<FolderTreeModel>() };

foreach (var path in paths)
{
    var parts = path.Split('/');
    ensureExists(root, parts);
}
```

I then get this result:

[image: result]

If you change the definition of `FolderTreeModel` to this:

```
public class FolderTreeModel : List<FolderTreeModel>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

...then the code gets a little simpler:

```
Action<FolderTreeModel, IEnumerable<string>> ensureExists = null;
ensureExists = (ftm, ts) =>
{
    if (ts.Any())
    {
        var title = ts.First();
        var child = ftm.Where(x => x.Title == title).SingleOrDefault();
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = new FolderTreeModel() { Title = title };
            ftm.Add(child);
        }
        ensureExists(child, ts.Skip(1));
    }
};

var root = new FolderTreeModel() { Title = "/" };
```

The rest of the code is the same.