# Sort List<string> based on character count

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting

Example:

```
List<string> folders = new List<string>();
folders.Add("folder1/folder2/folder3/");
folders.Add("folder1/");
folders.Add("folder1/folder2/");
```

I want to sort this list based on character i.e '/'
so my output will be 
folder1/ 
folder1/folder2/ 
folder1/folder2/folder3

Comment: What about `x/y/z/k` vs `folder1/folder2`?

Comment: And what does "based on character i.e. '/'" mean? Do you mean "count that specific character"? Or only the total string length?

Comment: What if the input was `folder1/` `folder1/folder2/` `folder1/folder3/` `folder1/folder2/folder4/` `folder11/`  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List<string> of Paths to Hierarchical structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947623/liststring-of-paths-to-hierarchical-structure)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - yes folder level matters

Answer (score 7):

LINQ:

```
folders = folders.OrderBy(f => f.Length).ToList(); // consider null strings
```

or `List.Sort`

```
folders.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.Length.CompareTo(s2.Length));
```

a safe approach if the list could contain null's:

```
folders = folders.OrderBy(f => f?.Length ?? int.MinValue).ToList();
```

---

If you actually want to sort by the folder-depth not string length:

```
folders = folders.OrderBy(f => f.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar).Length).ToList();
```

Comment: I think this will throw an exception if any of the strings in the list is null.

Comment: Your change was even better than my `f?.Length ?? 0` suggestion as it will now (correctly) sort null-strings before empty strings (which is the norm in most sort or ordering implementations in .NET)

Comment: This will not give the output the OP asked for, for example:
**m/pics/nat**
will come before
**mypersonal_stuff/pictures**, he wants a hierarchical order

Comment: @MohamedAhmed: Why you think that? OP has said: _"Sort List<string> based on character count"_. However, provided also a solution for that

Comment: @TimSchmelter - your answer of Path.DirectorySeparatorChar... helped ! thanks

Comment: @SampatPatil: you are welcome, feel free to accept an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you actually want to sort by name:

```
folders = folders.OrderBy(f => f).ToList();
```

Or simply:

```
folders.Sort();
```

This will work correctly for cases like this:

```
folder1/
folder1/subfolder1
folder1/subfolder1/subsubfolder
folder2
folder2/subfolder2
```

Sorting by length alone will consider `"folder1"` and `"folder2"` equal.