# How to resolve SystemUnauthorizedAccess Exception when accessing MyDocuments files in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2022, filesystemobject

I've got the following exception:

```
SystemUnauthorizedAccess Exception: Access to the path <path> is denied.
```

with the following code:

```
                foreach (string doc in Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(doc);
                }
```

I need to get all file names in the MyDocuments hierarchy.
Suggestions?

Comment: What is the value for the Path in the error message? Probably there are one or more folders or files that don't allow access to the current user running the code above. Did you try to run this code as administrator?

Comment: C:\Users\user1\Documents\Immagini, in a mixed language fashion. I ran as administrator and I got same error.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986293/access-to-the-path-is-denied-when-using-directory-getfiles)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947623/liststring-of-paths-to-hierarchical-structure check this out